# Determine and operate on the latest updated sequence in a CombineLatest

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am wondering if there was an existing operator or a certain logic that would allow me to reproduce the behavior of a `CombineLatest` with 2 source sequences, but with the added ability to determine which of the 2 sequences was modified last. I want to, in turn, use this distinction to change the way I operate when combining the latest result of both sequences.

I think that a good way to express what I want is by giving an example of a method signature that would implement the logic I am talking of.

```
public static IObservable<TResult> MyOperator<TInLeft, TInRight, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TInLeft> left, 
    this IObservable<TInRight> right, 
    Func<TInLeft, TInRight, bool, TResult> selector)
{
    // ...magic 
}
```

In this case, `left` and `right` would be the entry sequences and the `selector` func passed to the method would have its boolean parameter value set to `true` to indicate that it is the `left` sequence that was the source of the most recent change and `false` if it was the `right` sequence that changed last.

Of course, for the sake of clarity, the method could also be reformulated in the following way

```
public IObservable<TResult> MyOperator<TInLeft, TInRight, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TInLeft> left, 
    this IObservable<TInRight> right, 
    Func<TInLeft, TInRight, TResult> whenLeft,
    Func<TInLeft, TInRight, TResult> whenRight)
{
    // ... more magic
}
```

Where, instead of using a boolean to distinguish the most recently updated sequence, each sequence would have its own contained behavior in the form of a func.

A use case for such an operator would be that I want to have a shared result that depends on some combination of the `left` and `right` sequence (just like `CombineLatest`), but that priority is given to whichever has the newest information. I hope that my intent is clear enough to understand.

Is there an existing operator that has a similar underlying logic or that could be adapted to serve this purpose ? How could I accomplish such a behavior otherwise ? I have a vague idea of some operators that could be of use, but It seems like there could be a lot of different ways and I am just not sure of the best approach to take to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use the `Timestamp` operator in conjunction with `CombineLatest`. Something like this:

```
    var obs1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp();
    var obs2 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Timestamp();

    var result = Observable.CombineLatest(obs1, obs2, (v1, v2) =>
    {
        if(v1.Timestamp < v2.Timestamp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("v1 " + v1.Timestamp);
            return v1;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("v2 " + v1.Timestamp);
            return v2;
        }       
    });

    result.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Good work. You beat me to it. Just one small comment - your comparison operator is around the wrong way - it should be `<`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, fixed now. Really enjoy your posts.

Comment: Thanks. You do really? What do you enjoy about them?

Comment: You know a lot about Rx and the solutions you provide are always on the ball and well explained. I have played around with a few of them and they have worked very well.

Comment: That's much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do:

```
var combined =
    source1.Timestamp()
        .CombineLatest(source2.Timestamp(), (ts1, ts2) => new { ts1, ts2 });

combined.Select(x =>
    x.ts1.Timestamp < x.ts2.Timestamp
        ? "source1 first"
        : "source2 first");
```

Comment: Thank you both. That's one of the reasons I like Rx: you never stop learning. On another note, did you ever encounter this use case ?

Comment: @PhilGref - I must say I've never hit this particular use case.